# How to pass a reference in a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I need a class A containing a class B. I need to change a value from class A from class B, so I need to pass a reference to B constructor. That's what I'm doing now:

```
class A
{
    B b;
    float value = 50;

    A()
    {
        b = B(value);
    }
}


class B
{
    float& value;
    float otherValue = 50; // I've declared this variable because the default constructor needs a value for the reference, but I don't really want this variable.

    B() : value(otherValue){};
    
    B(float _value) : value(_value){};   
}
```

I get the error: "A &A::operator =(const A &): attempting to reference a deleted function". I know it's because of `B b;`, but I need to declare b as an attribute of A. What's the correct way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: You should use a pointer instead of a reference here. Reference data members, as you've just discovered, are problematic.

Comment: `B(_value)` is not valid C++. Did you mean `B(float& _value)`?

Answer (score 1):

This code works, but I did have to change the `float&` member in `B` to a `float`. Do you actually need to hold a reference to a float? There are a lot of ways that can go wrong.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B {
  float value = 50;

 public:
  B() = default;
  B(float _value) : value(_value){};
  float getVal() const { return value; }
};

class A {
  B b;

 public:
  A() = default;
  float getBVal() const { return b.getVal(); }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  std::cout << a.getBVal() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
50
```

As mentioned, `B` could hold a pointer to a float instead of a reference.

```cpp
class B {
  float* value = new float(50);

 public:
  B() = default;
  B(float _value) : value(new float(_value)){};
  ~B() {
    delete value;
    value = nullptr;
  }

  float getVal() const { return *value; }
};
```

You would also need (at a minimum) a copy constructor and assignment operator overload in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the reference in the member initializer list of A constructors e.g. the following will print 51, modifying A's value via a B.

```C++
class B
{
    float& value;

    public:
        B(float& v) : value(v) {};

        void modify_value() {
            value++;
        }
};

class A
{
    B b;
    float value;

    public:
        A() : value(50), b(value)
        {}

        void modify_value() {
            b.modify_value();
        }

        float get_value() const {
            return value;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.modify_value();
    std::cout << a.get_value() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you default construct `b`, then try to assign it. You get one chance to initialise the reference in `b`, so do it the member initialiser.

You also need to define `B` before `A`

It's also a good idea to declare `value` in `A` before `b`, so that it is initialised when you pass it to `B`'s constructor. It isn't a problem with your code, but if you look at it's value in `B::B` that would be undefined behaviour

```
class B
{
    float& value;
public:    
    B(float& _value) : value(_value){}
};

class A
{
    float value = 50;
    B b;
public:    
    A() : b(value) {} 
};
```

Comment: Worth noting `value` will be uninitialized at the time it is passed as `b`'s construction argument, but this is OK as long as it's actual value is not read until after the `value` object is initialized. Though it may be safer to simply put `value` before `b` in the `A` class' definition.

Comment: That does not work. B needs a default constructor, and `B b;` is causing the error "Attempting to reference a deleted function"

Comment: @PauRosello [No it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/124f5b8a6b122857). With those data members, `B` *must not* have a default constructor